# ОправдаНо или оправдаННо

Tags: удвоенные-буквы

"Это решение еще более дорогое, чем из хастеллоя, но в некоторых случаях оно оправдано".

Слово "оправдано" является кратким причастием, и соответственно пишется одно "н", или отглагольным прилагательным, где "н" удваивается?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Правильно: "Это решение еще более дорогое, чем из хастеллоя, но в некоторых случаях оно оправданно".
Это краткое прилагательное, так как значение переносное: оправданный - это правильный, верный, обоснованный.

Причастие с прямым значением действия используется в таких выражениях, как "все обвиняемые оправданы".

Answer (score 2):

"Краткие формы прилагательного оправданный (кроме формы мужского рода) пишутся с одной буквой н, если есть дополнение (оправданы важностью проекта), и с двумя н, если дополнения нет (его действия вполне оправданны; ваше беспокойство оправданно). См.: Русский орфографический словарь РАН / Под ред. В. В. Лопатина, О. Е. Ивановой. – 4-е изд., испр. и доп. – М., 2012. Поэтому правильно: цена оправдана качеством, удобством и широким набором функций." - ответ на аналогичный вопрос Грамота.ру

Comment: А "оправданный" точно прилагательное? От какого слова образовано?

Answer (score 1):

Правильно:

*Это решение еще более дорогое, чем из хастеллоя, но в некоторых случаях оно **оправданно.***

Это краткое прилагательное, так как значение переносное: **оправданный** – это правильный, верный, обоснованный.

**ОПРАВДАННЫЙ**

**Русский орфографический словарь**

оправданный; кр. ф. прич. -ан, -ана; **кр. ф. прил.** -ан, -ана (с дополн.: оправданы важностью проекта) и -**ан, -анна (без дополн.**: его действия вполне **оправданны**; ваше беспокойство **оправданно**)

Answer (score 0):

Ответ однозначный: оправданно. С двумя буквами Н.

Comment: Что значит ваше "однозначно": два н всегда всегда или только тут?