# Газетный спор о насущном

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

1)Ставка на молодежь оправдана?

2)Ставка на молодежь оправданна?

P.s. прошу тех, кто не разбирается не писать комментарии.

Comment: Ответы, как видите, далеко не краткие. Потому как без конкретной проблемной **полной** фразы или контекста однозначности в ответе быть не может. И заголовок... Не иначе, молодёжь читает газеты. С какого он потолка?

Comment: Ставка на молодежь оправдана.   В суде, что ли, оправдали?  // Ставка на молодежь оправданна (верна, обоснованна) Вот и весь ответ.  Зачем больше?)  Здесь и контекст не нужен.

Comment: @Максим Рогов Очень жаль, что вы не слышите разумных доводов и выбираете ложные варианты. Ваше дело!

Comment: а что не так с ними?

Comment: @МаксимРогов Посмотрите хотя бы практику письма по этому слову. Она все расставит по своим местам: https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CksqIQoICAAQChgyIAoQBSAAKNbxiJD9%2B9UHQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCHwodChsKA3JlcRIUChLQvtC%2F0YDQsNCy0LTQsNC90LAwAQ%3D%3D

Comment: Ложные доводы по участнику Ми Молли: Орфографический словарь РАН неверен, Грамота.ру дает неграмотные  ответы. Разумные довод только у Ми Молли.  Его и надо слушать.

Comment: Практика письма это всего лишь решения обычных пользователей, которые не смотрят в словарь РАН, а пишут по своему разумению. Им закон не писан. Кроме того, указания словаря могут корректироваться со временем.  Не надо отставать от жизни.

Comment: Убедили вы меня)))

Comment: В словаре я не вижу такого примера о котором пишу извините

Comment: Почему не видите.  В словаре РАН   дана информация про краткую форму прилагательного с вариантами:  НН – без дополнения, Н – с дополнением.  Русский орфографический словарь: оправданный; кр. ф. прич. -ан, -ана; кр. ф. ПРИЛ. -ан, -ана (с дополн.: оправданы важностью проекта) и -ан, -анна (без дополн.: его действия вполне оправданны; ваше беспокойство оправданно)

Comment: Еще больше запутался

Comment: Ну да, нарушайте правила, не стесняйтесь. Лингвисты в языке ничего не понимают. Теперь пользователи сам все решают! // Запутались? Почитайте ответы Грамоты.ру. Розенталь: В области орфографии желательна и необходима полная унификация, Или тоже отменяем? Словарь РАН - вот единственный закон, а иначе начнется беззаконие.  Законы не обсуждают, а исполняют в любом случае, нравятся они или не нравятся.

Comment: К моему примеру словарь не имеет прямого отношения я об этом.

Comment: @МаксимРогов
Различение отглагольных прилагательных и причастий – непростая тема. Здесь алгоритм, которым я пользуюсь, пока что не подводил еще https://zhi-shi.ai/ru-algo-pril-vs-prich.html , посмотрите, если интересно :)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [ОправдаНо или оправдаННо](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/37985/%d0%9e%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%9d%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%9d%d0%9d%d0%be)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выдумывать велосипед не буду и просто скопирую ответ с другого форума.

Оба варианта допустимы, но они дают умеющим читать разные смысловые оттенки.

После результата по смыслу подходит одна "н". (Сделанная ставка сыграла ==> оправдана (ставка выиграла); по смыслу — причастие)
До результата может подойти две "н". (Сделанная ставка имеет разумное объяснение, оправдание ==> оправданна (разумная ставка); по смыслу — прилагательное)
© Источник: https://rusforus.ru/viewtopic.php?t=13005

---

*На мой взгляд, возможен лишь первый вариант, потому что для написания "нн" не имеется условий: наречий меры и степени не присутствует, синонима-прилагательного не имеется, возможна глагольная замена.
При причастии зависимое слово может и подразумеваться, что говорит о том, что писать нужно "**н**".*

> опра́вданный, -ая, -ое, кратк. ф. -ан, -ана, сравн. ст. нет □ Имеющий
> оправдание (употр. с тв. п.)  | Его поведение опра́вдано
> обстоятельствами

Не могу не сказать и об ответе специалистов относительно слов подобного рода:

> 1. Правильно написание Количество товаров ограничено. В этой фразе отглагольное образование является причастием. Ограничено – это форма
>    глагола ограничить, обладающая глагольным значением 'поставить в
>    какие-либо границы, рамки; стеснить какими-либо условиями'. Признак
>    ограниченности процессуальный, временный: он существует столько,
>    сколько длится акция. В ситуации, описываемой фразой Количество
>    товаров ограничено, обязательно присутствует какой-то субъект
>    (например, руководитель компании), который ограничил количество
>    товаров.
> 2. Правильно написание Количество товаров ограниченно. Отглагольное признаковое слово можно считать формой прилагательного ограниченный. В
>    толковых словарях это прилагательное толкуется так: 'небольшой,
>    незначительный' (Ограниченные средства. Соль следует употреблять в
>    ограниченном количестве. Ограниченный обзор. Ограниченный круг
>    знакомых. Человек ограниченных способностей) и 'c недостаточными
>    знаниями, с узким кругозором' (Очень ограниченный и самоуверенный
>    человек. Ограниченные люди редко сомневаются в своих способностях). В
>    разбираемой фразе реализуется первое значение прилагательного:
>    количество товаров ограниченно означает, что товаров немного,
>    незначительно, мало. И это вполне может быть связано не с волей
>    некоего субъекта, а с тем, что товар просто заканчивается.
>    Соответствует этому рассуждению пример из «Русского орфографического
>    словаря»: наши возможности ограниченны.
> 3. Есть и еще одна – отчасти примиряющая – позиция. Во фразе возможны оба смысла, они нейтрализуются, то есть не различаются. Пишущий не
>    обязан знать обо всех нюансах ситуации, к тому же они могут быть
>    скрыты (не всегда компания, сообщающая об ограничении товаров, готова
>    обнародовать истинные причины своих действий). Далее рассуждения
>    переносятся с одного частного случая на весь корпус кратких
>    отглагольных образований. При нейтрализации возможны две стратегии
>    нормирования: 1) признать допустимой вариативность написаний, 2)
>    утвердить один вариант – с н или нн. Первая стратегия отражает
>    лингвистическую сущность явления, но она приведет к разнонаписаниям. А
>    это представляется плохим решением и для орфографии, и для пишущих.
>    Вся многовековая эволюция русского письма подчинена движению к
>    унификации, отказу от вариативности, даже лингвистически обоснованной.
>    Например, вполне возможно вариативное написание многих наречий и
>    ученые не раз предлагали узаконить его. Однако всякий раз дискуссия
>    приходила к тому, что орфографическая вариативность неудобна: пишущему
>    все равно придется выбирать между двумя вариантами и двоякие написания
>    будут мешать формированию зрительного облика слова, очень важного для
>    приобретения навыка беглого чтения.
>
> Из сказанного вытекает предложение, сейчас осторожно высказываемое
> некоторыми лингвистами при обсуждении этой болезненной темы. Можно
> было бы установить единое написание, не требующее различения кратких
> причастий и прилагательных. **Если такой выбор делать, то закреплять
> нужно написание с одним н, так как именно варианты с одним н абсолютно
> преобладают в практике письма. В пользу такого решения говорит и то,
> что в устной речи мы не используем для подобных слов никаких сигналов
> «причастности» или «прилагательности» и это никак не мешает
> взаимопониманию.**

---

Я также напомню, что правила правописания "н" и "нн" в причастиях и прилагательных до сих пор не изменены. **В орфографическом словаре от РАН представлена именно рекомендация писать слова тем или иным образом, о чем свидетельствуют слова самих лингвистов.**

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151791/discussion-on-answer-by------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 1):

Ставка какова? оправда(??)а.

Ставка какая? оправданная.

"Оправданная" – отглагольное прилагательное или причастие, зависимых слов нет. От глагола "оправдать" - что сделать, совершенный вид, есть приставка. Значит причастие, в полной форме пишется НН.

Раз зависимых слов нет, то возникает вопрос: произошел ли переход в отглагольное прилагательное в этом контексте? Можно ли сказать "Ставка, оправданная мной?" – нет, нельзя, ставку никто не оправдывает как таковую, употреблено не в значении "признать невиновным", а в переносном значении "имеет смысл", значит переход произошел.

А раз это прилагательное, то в краткой форме пишется столько же, сколько и в полной. В данном случае – две НН.

Ссылка на хорошую статью: https://rus.1sept.ru/article.php?ID=199902601

Answer (score 1):

(1) *Ставка на молодежь **оправданна*** (правильна, верна). Краткое прилагательное **без дополнения.**

(2) *Ставка на молодежь **оправдана** по многим показателям.* Краткое прилагательное **с дополнением.**

**Словари**

Русский орфографический словарь: **оправданный;** кр. ф. прич. -ан, -ана; кр. ф. прил. -ан, -ана (с **дополн**.: оправданы важностью проекта) и -ан, -анна (**без дополн**.: его действия вполне оправданны; ваше беспокойство оправданно)

**Большой толковый словарь русского языка.**

**ОПРАВДАННЫЙ**, -ая, -ое. Такой, который можно оправдать, объяснить, признать допустимым, целесообразным. О. риск. О. жест. О-ая остановка машины. Не совсем о. пропуск в тексте. О-ое молчание. // Закономерный, справедливый. О-ая обида. О-ое беспокойство родителей. Оправданно, нареч. О. и закономерно появилась в газете эта статья. Оправданность, -и; ж. О. действий. О. решения.

**[См. ответы Грамоты.ру](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&mode=all)**

Answer (score 0):

Держи правильный ответ:

*Ставка на молодëжь оправданна*.

Не благодари.

Comment: Прекрасный ответ, коротко и ясно.

Comment: Ответ ошибочен!

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае только "**оправдана**", потому что это краткое причастие, а не прилагательное.

```
§ 100. Краткие формы страдательных причастий прошедшего времени пишутся с одним н, напр.: читан, читана, читано, читаны; прочитан, прочитана, прочитано, прочитаны; мечен, мечена, мечено, мечены; помечен, помечена, помечено, помечены. Так же пишутся формы среднего рода в безличном употреблении, напр.: накурено, насорено, езжено, хожено, езжено-переезжено, хожено-перехожено.
```

Comment: Словарь РАН читайте,  Различайте причастия и прилагательные.  ОПРАВДАННЫЙ
Русский орфографический словарь
оправданный; кр. ф. прич. -ан, -ана; кр. ф. прил. -ан, -ана (с дополн.: оправданы важностью проекта) и -ан, -анна (без дополн.: его действия вполне оправданны; ваше беспокойство оправданно)   https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=оправданный&mode=slovari&dicts[]=71

Comment: А как же переход из причастий в отглагольные прилагательные? :)

Comment: Ответ Анны верен на 100%  (в отличие от ответов большинства других участников), а потому несправедливо заминусован.

Comment: "Краткое страдательное причастие можно заменить однокоренным глаголом в форме прошедшего времени:

стена (какова?) покрашена — стена, которую покрасили;
дело (каково?) сделано — дело, которое сделали.
"

Потрудитесь, пожалуйста, сделайте глагольную замену здесь

Answer (score 0):

**Второй ответ (комментарий)**

```
Выдумывать велосипед не буду и просто СКОПИРУЮ ответ 
с другого форума.
```

**Материал** по ссылке участника @Ми Молли и **по теме заданного вопроса**

https://rusforus.ru/viewtopic.php?t=13005

*В газете спор вышел по поводу заголовка **"Ставка на молодежь оправдаНа"**. Так написала автор текста, другая журналистка ее поддержала, а **КОРРЕКТОР настаивала на НН**. Хотя я вообще не филолог, обратились ко мне, словно на справочный портал: "**Срочно, срочно, газета сдается!**" :D Посоветовал ***НН***.*

*Так и сдали, после чего автор написала мне про образование кратких причастий, глаголы несовершенного и совершенного вида и т. п. Я в этом мало что смыслю, но она сделала вывод, что у нее однозначно **краткое причастие с одним Н,** без вариантов.*

*Посоветовал ей поискать **в Сети** ответ на свою конкретную ситуацию (этих ответов про "оправда(Н)На" - **воз и маленькая тележка),** но **ПЕРЕУБЕДИТЬ** так и не смог. Мол, там ошибка, противоречие правилам русского языка.*

*Мой вопрос вот в чем: есть ли такие ПРАВИЛА в которых однозначно и без вариантов одно ***Н***? Откуда-то она ведь это взяла.*

© Источник: https://rusforus.ru/viewtopic.php?t=13005

**ПРИМЕЧАНИЯ**

1. **Обсуждение** проходит **и сейчас**. Форум мне знакомый, приходилось там бывать. Это обычный **форум-чат** разговорного типа. Особых требований к вопросам-ответам нет. Мнения по данному вопросу **разные,** как и следовало ожидать.
2. Участники вообще по большей части в справочники  и учебные пособия **не смотрят**, а вспоминают то, что учили **когда-то**. И что характерно: никаких **ССЫЛОК** на правила нет, хотя автору вопроса нужно было именно правило. Но там вообще **НЕ ПРИНЯТО** давать или спрашивать ссылки.
3. Аналогично **нет никаких ссылок** у участника @Ми Молли, ответ которого был принят. **А ПОЧЕМУ?** Это вообще ответ, **очень странно построенный**. Большая его часть **не по теме вопроса** (разбирается другой пример, даются общие рассуждения).