# Оправданны или оправданы (чем): почему дополнение меняет форму написания краткого прилагательного?

Tags: нн, краткое-прилагательное, н

**[ОПРАВДАННЫЙ](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&mode=slovari&dicts%5B%5D=42&dicts%5B%5D=71)**

```
   Русский орфографический словарь
   оправданный; кр. ф. прич. -ан, -ана; кр. ф. прил. 
   -ан, -ана (с дополн.: ОПРАВДАНЫ важностью 
   проекта) и -ан, -анна (без дополн.: его действия 
   вполне ОПРАВДАННЫ; ваше беспокойство оправданно)
```

Информация о коррекции ***НН/Н*** для кратких прилагательных  при наличии дополнения дана **[в словаре РАН](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&mode=slovari&dicts%5B%5D=42&dicts%5B%5D=71).**  И тогда возникает вопрос: почему надо учитывать **именно дополнение?**

**ВЫВОД**

Какой же ответ, в чем **смысл этой КОРРЕКЦИИ?**

**В общем** случае отглагольные прилагательные (две буквы НН) отличаются от причастий (одна буква Н) **переносным** (не прямым) значением.

Но есть **ОСОБАЯ ГРУППА** отглагольных прилагательных, для которых возможен выбор ***НН*** или ***Н.*** Они тоже имеют **переносное** значение, как и все отглагольные прилагательные, но при этом могут **управлять дополнением** в форме Т.п., как и причастия. Это **сближает** их с причастиями, и тогда при наличии дополнения в них пишется **одна буква Н.**

Таким образом, для **особой группы** отглагольных прилагательных характерно: **ПЕРЕНОСНОЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ** (как у прилагательных) + **УПРАВЛЕНИЕ ПАДЕЖОМ** (как у причастий).

**РОЗЕНТАЛЬ, пункт 8** тоже говорит о дополнениях, и не только: 8. Некоторые **прилагательные** допускают двоякое написание краткой формы в зависимости от значения и **конструкции.** Ср.:

```
 Сестра намерена вскоре уехать (‘имеет намерение’ — 
 в сочетании с инфинитивом). Его дерзость намеренна 
 (‘нарочита’ — без инфинитива).
 Мы преданы Родине (в сочетании с формой дательного 
 падежа). Старые друзья всегда преданны (без 
 дополнения).
 Наши легкоатлеты уверены в победе (с дополнением).
 Движения гимнастов легки и уверенны (без дополнения)
```

Comment: Мой вопрос предельно конкретен, как и ответ на него. О каких дополнениях говориться в словаре РАН?  Почему именно дополнения, а не любые зависимые слова? Кто мне может ответить на этот вопрос? Я ответила! Хотелось бы услышать такое же конкретное мнение. В одно предложение можно уложиться.

Comment: Вопрос минусовали.  Почему?  Знать не желаем словарь РАН или ко мне какие претензии?

Answer (score 1):

1. **История вопроса**

Всем известно, что краткие формы страдательных **причастий** (одна Н) надо отличать от кратких форм **прилагательных** (две НН): **[Розенталь, пункт 7:](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=62#pp62)** Суд не усмотрел в данном деле состава преступления, и обвиняемые были ***оправданы***. Чрезвычайные меры в этих условиях были необходимы и вполне ***оправданны.***

В этом случае говорят о **переносном (не прямом)** значении отглагольного прилагательного. **[И в 2014 году](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/37985/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%9D%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%9D%D0%9D%D0%BE)** участники форума однозначно решают подобную задачу,  хотя при этом не дают ссылок на орфографический словарь РАН.

**Предложение**: *Это решение еще более дорогое, чем из хастеллоя, но в некоторых случаях оно **оправданно***.  Но там и **нет ДОПОЛНЕНИЯ.**

2. **[В 2024 году](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/479995/%D0%93%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC)** решение вызывает затруднения, споры и непонимание  темы. Потому что вопрос видится как задача **с тремя НЕИЗВЕСТНЫМИ**: (1) причастие, (2) прилагательное без дополнения и (3) прилагательное с дополнением.

**ВОПРОС:** Как правильно?  1) Ставка на молодежь ***оправдана***? 2) Ставка на молодежь ***оправданна***? P.s. прошу тех, кто не разбирается, не писать комментарии.

```
    — Ставка на молодежь оправдана. В суде, что ли, 
    оправдали?  Ставка на молодежь оправданна 
    (верна, обоснованна). Вот и весь ответ. Зачем 
    больше?) Здесь и контекст не нужен.

    — Очень жаль, что вы не слышите разумных доводов 
     и выбираете ложные варианты. Ваше дело! 
     Посмотрите хотя бы практику письма по этому 
     слову. Она все расставит по своим местам.
              
     В словаре я не вижу такого примера о котором 
     пишу извините. 
     И т.д.
```

Это прилагательное (с переносным значением), дополнения нет, так что по правилам и по словарю РАН там пишется ***НН***.

3. Решение задачи **в словаре РАН** известно многим, но еще не всем. Там  рассматриваются **три возможных случая:**

**Оправданный;** кр. ф. **прич**. -ан, -ана; кр. ф. **прил**. -ан, -ана (с **дополн**.: оправданы важностью проекта) и -ан, -анна (**без дополн**.: его действия ***вполне оправданны***; ваше беспокойство ***оправданно***).

4. Итак, в некоторых кратких прилагательных (не причастиях!)  возможно написание **одной Н** (об этом говорил еще Розенталь в примечании [к пункту 7](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=62#pp62)). Но почему требуется наличие именно **дополнения?**
5. Надо посмотреть значение глагола ***оправдать*** в толковом словаре:

**Прямое** значение (**оправдать в суде**) обозначено в пункте (1), в этом случае образуется **причастие**. Все остальные значения по сути **переносные**, и тогда это будут **прилагательные.** Но в значении (2) и (3) возможно наличие **дополнения** (чем). Коррекция ***НН/Н*** делается именно для **таких** прилагательных.

**ВЫВОД.** Русский орфографический словарь РАН предлагает для подобных задач решение, которое **исключает ненужные споры.** И не нужно говорить о том, что лингвисты постоянно **меняют** информацию. Об особом статусе некоторых отглагольных прилагательных писал еще **Розенталь,** но в настоящий момент словарь дает **точные и конкретные** указания для выбора формы письма.

**СЛОВАРИ**

**ОПРАВДАТЬ**, св. кого-что. 1. **кого.** **Вынести судебный приговор,** содержащий признание подсудимого невиновным, не заслуживающим наказания. О. подсудимого. Суд оправдал его. Подростков оправдали за недостатком улик. 2. **кого (чем).** **Признать правым, поступившим непредосудительно**. Нельзя о. его за пассивность. Ты не сказал про двойку, тут я не могу о. тебя. **3. что (чем).** **Признать что-л. допустимым, возможным, непредосудительным.** О. чьи-л. действия. Трудно о. его поступок. Жестокость нельзя о. О. поступок молодостью. О. преступление его непреднамеренностью. 4. **Показать себя достойным** чего-л., заслуживающим чего-л. О. надежды. Я должен о. ваши ожидания. О. высокое звание учителя. 5. **Возместить, окупить.** **О. расходы, потери.** О. покупку машины. Дорогостоящая техника оправдала себя (окупилась, возместив затраты).

**ОПРАВДАННЫЙ**, -ая, -ое. Такой, который можно оправдать, **объяснить, признать допустимым, целесообразным.** О. риск. О. жест. О-ая остановка машины. Не совсем о. пропуск в тексте. О-ое молчание. // **Закономерный, справедливый**. О-ая обида. О-ое беспокойство родителей. Оправданно, нареч. О. и закономерно появилась в газете эта статья. Оправданность, -и; ж. О. действий. О. решения.

Comment: Вопрос минусовали.  Почему?  Знать не желаем словарь РАН или ко мне какие претензии?